# How to make my iPhone app compatible with iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, compatibility, iphone-sdk-3.1

My iphoneos 3.1 based application is not working on iOS 4 GM: the camera is not showing in full screen, it doesn't correctly detects compass information, the uiwebviews doesn't respond to touches (they don't scroll), and so on. It's completely broken! Now my question is: how can I develop an update using the latest xcode with support for ios 4? The latest iOS 4 xcode (3.2.3) doesn't provide any way to develop for iPhoneOS 3.x ("base sdk missing"). By the other side, xcode 3.2.2 would not allow me to debug it on a iOS 4 device, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode, you can use a later base SDK while *targeting* an earlier version.

Go into your project settings and set *iPhone OS Deployment Target* to an earlier version, such as "iPhone OS 3.1".

Answer (score 0):

I would create a second disk partition and install the 4.0 version of xcode on that. Keep the 3.2 version on your primary drive.

Its probably not necessary to create a second disk partition but it was simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

Install the 4.0 sdk under a different folder and then re-install the 3.2 sdk and develop in that.